# Group of order 175 is Abelian

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Question:
>
> Prove that any group of order 175 is Abelian.

The solution:

[image]

I am unable to understand why the intersection of the normal subgroups is the trivial intersection.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The intersection of two groups is a group. By Lagrange's theorem, the order of a subgroup of a group divides the order of the group. Thus $|P\cap Q| \mid |P|=7$ and $|P\cap Q| \mid |Q|=5 \text{ or }25$  thus $|P\cap Q|=1$ and...

Comment: $Q$ has order $25$?

Comment: I think they left out the Sylow for Sylow 5-subgroup. You can see that they refer to $Q \cong \mathbb{Z}_{25}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$ later in the proof.

Comment: @Hwai-RayTung I mean either way it doesn't matter. If $Q$ has order $5$ or $25$ the proof is the same.

Comment: Sylow directly implies existence of group of order $25$ and it is important that $G \cong P \times Q$ for the proof but I do agree that it doesn't matter for OP's specific question on the proof.

Comment: @Hwai-RayTung Yes you are right, I didn't read the full proof! Sorry lol